# how to do below table structure using Mysql,PHP is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql

```
s  Date     Kilometer
B3 2017-02-03   23332
B4 2017-02-10   23475
B5 2017-02-12   23875
B6 2017-02-14   24175
B7 2017-02-18   24875
B8 2017-02-24   25125
B9 2017-02-27   25775

Total (SUM) 2443
```

> =((B4-B3)+(B5-B4)+(B6-B5)+(B7-B6)+(B8-B7)+(B9-B8)),

I want like this total sum using Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

First give a row number based on the order of `s` column. Then use this result set and join it with itself.

**Query**

```
set @rn := 0;
select (t1.`kilometer`) - (t2.`kilometer`) `km` from(
    select @rn := @rn + 1 as `rn`, `s`, `date`, `kilometer`
    from `your_table_name`
    order by length(`s`), `s`
)t1
join (
    select @rn := @rn + 1 as `rn`, `s`, `date`, `kilometer`
    from `your_table_name`
    order by length(`s`), `s`
)t2
on t1.`rn`  = t2.`rn` - 1;
```